# Invoking-Command for Exchange in Powershell - block is not allowed in a Data section

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

What I'm trying to do is run this script:

```
$WPFcmdCreateNewUser.Add_Click({

$ScriptBlockContent = {
    param ($first,
        $last,
        $upn,
        $ou,
        $password
    )
    $encryptedpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
    New-RemoteMailbox -Name $name -OnPremisesOrganizationalUnit $ou -UserPrincipalName $upn -FirstName $first -LastName $last -Password $encryptedpass -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false
}
    $ex = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://SERVERNAME/PowerShell/
    Invoke-Command -Session $ex -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList ($WPFtxtNewFirstName.Text, $WPFtxtNewLastName.Text, $WPFtxtNewAlias.Text, $WPFcboNewOU.SelectedItem.Content, $WPFtxtNewPassword.Text)
})
```

But it's giving me the error:

```
ERROR: A Begin statement block, Process statement block, or parameter statement is not allowed in a Data section.
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidScriptBlockInDataSection
ERROR:     + PSComputerName        : SERVERNAME
```

I'm running the whole command from a button click in a XAML Powershell GUI. I googled alot trying to solve the problem as I usually do but no luck :(

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Exchange uses restricted language mode for remote sessions and you can't execute scriptblocks in your session.

> As a security feature, the language mode is obviously controlled at
>   the server (Exchange), so **if you want to enable execution of
>   scriptblocks you need to interactively logon (RDP or console) to
>   Exchange and create a new session configuration via
>   Register-PSSessionConfiguration.** You may then connect to Exchange
>   using this session configuration via New-PSSession -ConfigurationName
>   and you will then be able to execute scriptblocks by passing this
>   session instance to Invoke-Command -Session.

Reference:

- [Remote powershell scriptblock execution question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/46767d4b-e338-4bff-a38e-63b4d4903408/remote-powershell-scriptblock-execution-question)

Comment: ERROR: New-PSSession : [SERVERNAME] Connecting to remote server SERVERNAME failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the
    ERROR: request. Cannot find the Scripting session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the SERVERNAME computer. For more information, see the
    ERROR: about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Thank you for the help! So I tried this, and Registered a new PSSessionConfiguration, and when I try to use it this is the error I get now. I think it's because it's on Powershell 2.0... but I tried to use Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Scripting -PSVersion 3.0 and it says no such thing as -PSVersion. It's exchange management console 2010... why ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old bump here, but seeing as it is rather high on Google search I figured I could add how I fixed this issue:

```
$DomainCredential = (Get-Credential)
$fqdn = "<The fully qualified domain name of the target server>"

#Creates a session to the Exchange Remote Management Shell so that we can run Exchange commands. Use https:// if you have a proper setup with certificates. ( Mine was in test env )
$ConfigSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$fqdn/powershell `
          -Credential $DomainCredential -Authentication Kerberos

#Imports the module that exists in the session, in this case, Exchange Management -AllowClobber gives the imported commands presedence.
          Import-Module (Import-PSSession $ConfigSession -AllowClobber)
```

This imports the Exchange Commands as you would in a local session. The Exchange commands will still be executed on the remote server. Remember to close the session when done.